# Microsoft OCR API with PHP

Tags: php, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I am fairly new to PHP and I am trying to use the Microsoft OCR API. I already have my key and it is working as I have tested here: https://brazilsouth.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/unified-vision-apis-public-preview-2023-04-01-preview/operations/61d65934cd35050c20f73ab6/console.

So what I am trying to do is make a PHP API request. I cannot install any libraries to do this as it is a requirement for what I am doing. So I am trying to use the CURL and because of my newness in PHP don't know if this is the best approach nor whats wrong with it.

The request the above mentioned web page is as follow:

[image]

Here is the code that I have:

```
<?php
class Computer_Vision{

    public function __construct(){          
        $this->azure_ocr="https://brazilsouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/computervision/imageanalysis:analyze?api-version=2023-04-01-preview&features=read&language=pt HTTP/1.1";
        $this->subscription_key="blahblahblah";
    }
    
    public function recognize($image_url){

        $data = array("url" => $image_url);
        
        $azure_url = $this->azure_ocr;
        print($azure_url . "<br/>");
        
        $key=$this->subscription_key;
        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        print($data_string . "<br/>");
        
        $curl = curl_init($azure_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:'.$key
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        print("response: " . $response . "<br/>");
        
        
        if(curl_error($curl)) {
            print('error:' . curl_error($curl));
        } else {
            $json_object = json_decode($response, true);
            print("json_object: " . $json_object);
        }
        
        curl_close($curl);
    }
}
?>
```

On my index.php I have:

```
<?php 
    $azure = new Computer_Vision();
    $image_url = "https://portal.vision.cognitive.azure.com/dist/assets/OCR1-6dda571d.jpg";
    $ocr = $azure->recognize($image_url, "ocr");
?>
```

The code above doesn't give me any errors (at least it does not enter the curl_error condition) but it gives me an empty response

What would be the best way to do this? What I am doing wrong? Any help is more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft OCR API with PHP

You can use the code below to analyse the image with computer vision of the image URL.

**Code:**

```
<?php
class Computer_Vision {
    private $azure_ocr;
    private $subscription_key;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->azure_ocr = "https://<resourcename>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/computervision/imageanalysis:analyze?api-version=2023-02-01-preview&features=read&language=en&gender-neutral-caption=False";
        $this->subscription_key = "your-subscription-key"; 
    }

    public function recognize($image_url) {
        $data = array("url" => $image_url);
        $azure_url = $this->azure_ocr;
        $key = $this->subscription_key;
        $data_string = json_encode($data);

        $curl = curl_init($azure_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ' . $key
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        if (curl_error($curl)) {
            print('Error: ' . curl_error($curl));
        } else {
            $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if ($http_status == 200) {
                // Decode the JSON response and format it with proper indentation and spacing
                $formatted_response = json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, 512) . PHP_EOL;
                echo $formatted_response;
            } else {
                print("HTTP Status Code: " . $http_status . "\n");
                print("Response: " . $response);
            }
        }

        curl_close($curl);
    }
}

$azure = new Computer_Vision();
$image_url = "https://portal.vision.cognitive.azure.com/dist/assets/OCR1-6dda571d.jpg";
$azure->recognize($image_url);
?>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Call the Image Analysis API - Azure AI services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/how-to/call-analyze-image?tabs=rest#determine-how-to-process-the-data)